# Java writes wrong data into array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm implementing algorithm which will count the appearance of unique numbers in linked list. The problem is in the for loop in which I'm counting the appearance, when the input is something like `1 1 1 2 2 2`

Instead of getting for output

> 1 appearance 3 times 
>   2 appearance 3 times

I'm getting

> 1 appearance 3 
>   0 appearance 0

Wiht the input `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` I got array out of index exception. Here's the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = user_input.nextLine();
    //Getting user input, if the user enter an empty line(enter, enter) the loop will die
    while(input.length() > 0){
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(input));
        input = user_input.nextLine();
    }
    Collections.sort(list); //sorting the input
    //Getting the number of unique numbers
    int count_of_unique_numbers = 1;// There will be atleast one unique number

    if(!list.isEmpty()){
        int temp = list.get(0);
        for(int i = 1;i < list.size(); i++){
            if(temp != list.get(i)){
                count_of_unique_numbers++;
                temp = list.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The list is empty"); 
        return;
    } 
    //Counting how many times the unique numbers apper;
    int number_appearance[][] = new int[count_of_unique_numbers][2];
    int temp = list.get(0);
    int counter = 1;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i < list.size();i++){
        if(temp == list.get(i)){ counter++; }
        else{
            number_appearance[j][0] = temp;
            number_appearance[j][1] = counter;
            counter = 1;
            temp = list.get(i);
            j++;
        }
    }
    //Printing the number_appearance array
    for(int i = 0; i < count_of_unique_numbers; i++){
        System.out.println("The number: " + number_appearance[i][0] + " appearece " + number_appearance[i][1] + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception, and have you debugged through it?

Comment: (You should also consider that you never write the final number into your list of appearances, because you only write that when you spot a *different* number.)

Comment: In the third for loop, in the if condition when I try to get the ith element [ temp == list.get(i) ]

Comment: How do you know that "there will be atleast one unique number" *before* checking your list for being empty?

Comment: I check it look at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by adding the number of occurences of the final number, which you currently miss :

```
for(int i = 1;i < list.size();i++){
    if(temp == list.get(i)){ counter++; }
    else{
        System.out.println(temp+":"+counter);
        number_appearance[j][0] = temp;
        number_appearance[j][1] = counter;
        counter = 1;
        temp = list.get(i);
        j++;
    }
}
number_appearance[j][0] = temp; // added
number_appearance[j][1] = counter; // added
```

Input :

```
1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Output :

```
The number: 1 appearece 3 times
The number: 2 appearece 3 times
```

Input :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Output :

```
The number: 1 appearece 1 times
The number: 2 appearece 1 times
The number: 3 appearece 1 times
The number: 4 appearece 1 times
The number: 5 appearece 1 times
The number: 6 appearece 1 times
The number: 7 appearece 1 times
The number: 8 appearece 1 times
The number: 9 appearece 1 times
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply all of that down to this.

```
Map < String, Integer > numMap = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System. in );
String input = user_input.nextLine();

String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
for (String s: inputArray) {
    if (numMap.containsKey(s)) {
        numMap.put(s, numMap.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        numMap.put(s, 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > entry: numMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("number: " + entry.getKey() + " appeared: " + entry.getValue() + " times");
}
```

Comment: Well, if you change the key of that Map to type String, then you can avoid the conversion to integer and you don't need to care if the user really entered a number or not.

Comment: Very true, i have updated the answer to reflect that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
List<Integer> foundNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    if(foundNumbers.contains(list.get(i))
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i) + " appearance " + Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i) + " times.");
        foundNumbers.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Note that Collections.frequency is available since JDK 1.6

Comment: This is exercices i don't need it for any software. And i want to make the algorithm myself. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you originally were trying to do, but it would be easier to do it using `Map`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = user_input.nextLine();
    // Getting user input, if the user enter an empty line(enter, enter) the loop will die
    while (input.length() > 0) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(input));
        input = user_input.nextLine();
    }
    Collections.sort(list); // sorting the input
    Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i : list) {
        if (count.containsKey(i)) {
            count.put(i, count.get(i) + 1);
        }
        else {
            count.put(i, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> num : count.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("The number: " + num.getKey() + " appearece " + num.getValue() + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still unfamiliar with maps. But thank you I will keep this piece of code until I read the theory about them.

Comment: @austinwernli Not the same, you corrected some spelling errors :)